# Toolbar menu displaying, but not clickable when fragment is implemented

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, toolbar

Whenever I use the SectionsStateManager in the onCreate method to get the fragment to be displayed, the toolbar is still visible (along with its menu items) but is completely unclickable. The code for my MainActivity's onCreate method, my fragment's (MainFeed) onCreateView method, and my SectionsStatePagerAdapter is below.

**UPDATE:** *activity_main* is also included

**MainActivity's onCreate**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");

        RedditClient redditClient = new RedditClient(UserAgent.of("android",
                "com.digitalnode.feedr", "v0.0.1", "TheFiveHundred"));
        TokenStore store = new RedditTokenStore(
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this));
        RefreshTokenHandler refreshTokenHandler = new RefreshTokenHandler(store, redditClient);

        AuthenticationManager manager = AuthenticationManager.get();
        manager.init(redditClient, refreshTokenHandler);

        main_auth_manager = manager;

        mSectionsStatePagerAdapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        //setup the pager
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
```

**My Fragment's onCreateView Method**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_feed_layout, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started.");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        redditClient = new RedditClient(UserAgent.of("android",
                "com.digitalnode.feedr", "v0.0.1", "TheFiveHundred"));
        TokenStore store = new RedditTokenStore(
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()));
        RefreshTokenHandler refreshTokenHandler = new RefreshTokenHandler(store, redditClient);

        AuthenticationManager manager = AuthenticationManager.get();
        manager.init(redditClient, refreshTokenHandler);

        Entry[] arr = new Entry[entryList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = entryList.get(i);
        }
        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        Log.d("posts", "" + entryList);
        mAdapter = new EntryAdapter(arr);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //if(redditIsLoggedIn())
            //new SetUpReddit().execute();

        return view;
    }
```

**SectionsStatePagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

**activity_main Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout = "@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue in the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah, but I have no idea what could be wrong with it. I added the code just now, you can take a look at it if you'd like.

Comment: Yeah, the `ViewPager` appears to be covering the `Toolbar`, and consuming all of the touch events. I don't use `ConstraintLayout`, but I _think_ you could remedy that with your current setup by adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tool_bar"` to the `<ViewPager>` tag. Otherwise, changing the `<ConstraintLayout>` to a simple `<LinearLayout>` with `android:orientation="vertical"` would definitely do it.

Comment: @MikeM. That did the trick! Thank you so much.